# Sliding up/down a div - what's wrong with this code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, hide, toggle, show

I'm writing a simple script to slide up/down a toolbar `div (position: fixed)` when a button is clicked. But nothing happens when I click the button, not even the `alert`.

There seems to be something wrong with the animate part of the script, as if I take the animate part out then the alert will be played.

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hidebutton").click(function () {
            alert('hide clicked');
            $("#toolbarcontainer").animate({
                bottom: '-50px' //slide toolbar down so it's hidden
            }, 500);
            $(".footer").animate({
                margin-bottom: '10px'  //slide footer back
            }, 500);
            $("#hidebutton").fadeOut();
            $("#showbutton").fadeIn();
        });
        $("#showbutton").click(function () {
            alert('show clicked');
            $("#toolbarcontainer").animate({
                bottom: '0'  //slide toolbar back up
            }, 500);
            $(".footer").animate({
                margin-bottom: '90px'  //slide footer up again
            }, 500);
            $("#showbutton").fadeOut();
            $("#hidebutton").fadeIn();
        });

    });
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#toolbarcontainer {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:80px;
bottom:0;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
filter:alpha(opacity = 80);
}
#showbutton,#hidebutton {
position:absolute;
right:25px;
top:5px;
height:10px;
width:10px;
cursor:pointer;
}
#showbutton {
display:none;  //hide until toggled
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="toolbarcontainer">
    //contents of toolbar
    <div id="showbutton"><img src="../../site/pictures/showbutton.png"></div>
    <div id="hidebutton"><img src="../../site/pictures/hidebutton.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post it on jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add quotes `margin-bottom` to `'margin-bottom'`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hidebutton").click(function () {
        alert('hide clicked');
        $("#toolbarcontainer").animate({
            bottom: '-50px' //slide toolbar down so it's hidden
        }, 500);
        $(".footer").animate({
            'margin-bottom': '10px'  
        }, 500);
        $("#hidebutton").fadeOut();
        $("#showbutton").fadeIn();
    });
    $("#showbutton").click(function () {
        alert('show clicked');
        $("#toolbarcontainer").animate({
            bottom: '0'  
        }, 500);
        $(".footer").animate({
            'margin-bottom': '90px'  //slide footer up again
        }, 500);
        $("#showbutton").fadeOut();
        $("#hidebutton").fadeIn();
    });

});
```

Comment: It needs a quote because it's a property of the object passed as the argument. A dash `-` doesn't parse correctly without quotes. I think that could be worded more accurately, but that's my off-the-top-of-my-head answer. (Dash is normally used as the [subtraction operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/9ty8kw3w(v=vs.94).aspx), so it needs to be defined as a string literal instead).